# Nativescript - Https request not working on android platform v7.0.1

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I´m completely lost on why this is happening, on previous versions everything worked well and on ios i don´t have any problems, but on android the below crashes:(i´m using the [https](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-https/) module

```
https.request({
        url: "https://my_link",
        method: "POST",
        body:{ "grupo": gotData.tappedItem.grupo },
        allowLargeResponse:true,
        headers:{
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    }).then((response) => {
```

**And this also crashes:**

```
https.request({
        url: "https://my_link?grupo="+gotData.tappedItem.grupo,
        method: "GET",
        allowLargeResponse:true,
        headers:{
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    }).then((response) => {
```

Is it the code? am i typing anything wrong?. I already tried deleting the platforms and delete from the device, and i have download the certificate to app/assets folder but it just doesn´t work and this is the error:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onResponse failed
System.err: Error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: onResponse(file: node_modules/nativescript-https/https.android.js:492:0)
```

**My tns info:**

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 7.1.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 7.1.4 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/ios has 7.1.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/android has 7.0.1 version and is up to date.
```

Comment: why u use that plugin? is the https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http not enought?

Comment: Not it isn´t...apple demands https

Comment: but the http module can make https requests too

Comment: I did not know that, could you point me where that is in the docs?

Comment: in the code axamples they make calls to https urls. so if you do not use SSL pinning or any other extra features of this plugin, the http module should be enought